# How can I enumerate all the file in a directory in vfs c or c++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, vfs

I need to enumerate all the file in a folder and then navigate to the subfolder and do the same (recursion? sure).

Ideally the algorithm should work in the same way on linux & macos

DISCLAIMER: I have asked a similar question on POSIX: I'm now aware of VFS but I'm puzzled to use VFS for enumerate dir. Any suggestion ? Should I open a dir as file ? The only way is to use a library cross platform like qt ?

UPDATE: so no **VFS** way to work on directory? "**V**irtual **F**ile **S**ystem provides a single API for accessing various different file systems" but no way to enumerate directory.

The "readdir" etc solution will do the trick on any type of *NIX ? And on windows nothing better than the huge MingW lib? or partial impletion working on only some win like:
 https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/tools/TexturePacker/Win32/dirent.c

The BOOST seem to be a really cool  solution but it's complex and academic. thnks in any case

**LAST UPDATE**:
I have found some more doc and now everything is a lot more clear. 
**This question is a duplicate!** 
opendir() and readdir() are the solution to enumerate and browse directory on linux. As shown on my example is quite easy to map them on windows (but the incoerent windowz fs make everything strange) and ntfw() is even more useful.

**VFS** (the virtual file switch) is a kernel feature that resolves this problem by creating an abstraction layer for file-system operations. closed doc here: [linux programming interface](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/linux/9781593272203/file-systems/the_virtual_file_system_open_parenthesis)

thnks!

Comment: Not really a dupe since C++ might have better alternatives.

Comment: Are you looking for C++ or C? Either pick one, or explain in your question why you need both.

Comment: I 'm intersted in a C simple and easy solution that I will wrap in a cpp container. To better undestand I have created a quick github project with a simple windows test in a single c file here: https://github.com/maborg/scandir feel free to fork an modify. just for fun off course (the pertinent c file is here: https://github.com/maborg/scandir/blob/master/scandir/readdir.c )

Comment: and also I'm attempting to understand if there is a "standard" solution (VFS ? )

Comment: Aside: Can you provide a link to VFS? I'd like to update the tag wiki. Specifically, are you referring to http://commons.apache.org/vfs/ ?

Comment: I have found some more doc and now everything is a lot more clear. This question is a duplicate! opendir() and readdir() are the solution to enumerate and browse directory on linux. As shown on my example is quite easy to map them on windows (but the incoerent windowz fs make everything strange) ntfw() is even more useful. VFS (the virtual file switch) is a kernel feature that resolves this problem by creating an abstraction layer for file-system operations. doc here: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/linux/9781593272203/file-systems/the_virtual_file_system_open_parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix/Linux/Windows all have versions of [readdir()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir). You can use it to get what the file system knows about files.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at `nftw`.  Here's an example that just recursively prints the contents of a directory in C (Untested):

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ftw.h>


int
print( const char *path, const struct stat *s, int flag, struct FTW *f )
{
    puts( path );
    return 0;
}


int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    while( *++argv ) {
        if( nftw( *argv, print, 1024, FTW_DEPTH )) {
            perror( *argv );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it using [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm):

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  for ( boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end, dir("./");
    dir != end; ++dir ) {
    // std::cout << *dir << "\n";  // full path
    std::cout << dir->path().filename() << "\n"; // just last bit
  }
}
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {

  std::copy(
    boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator("./"),
    boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(),
    std::ostream_iterator<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```